# How does ObservableCollection<T>.Add work?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I was trying to implement a specialized collection that works like `ObservableCollection` to encapsulate some more mechanisms in it, to do that i also let my collection inherit from `Collection` and i also implement the same interfaces.

I just do not get though how one actually implements the whole collection-changed-logic, for example `Collection<T>.Add` is not being overridden (it is not even marked as virtual), so how does the `ObservableCollection` fire the `CollectionChanged` event if items were added using that method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your specific question, `Collection<T>.Add` calls the `InsertItem` virtual method (after checking that the collection is not read-only). `ObservableCollection<T>` indeed overrides this method to do the insert *and* raise the relevant change notifications.

Comment: Ah, so that's how that works, thank you once again! (How do you even know that?)

Comment: @H.B., have you heard of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)?

Comment: @Darin I have but they told me it costs money now and they will hunt me down if I leave a copy on my system http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-04.html

Comment: @H.B., nobody forces you to use V7. But I must say that it's a crappy decision from RedGate to make the best .NET tool ever being paid.

Comment: @Darin: All of the versions are time-bombed, so our free ride is going to come to an end soon no matter what.

Comment: @Ani, yeah, that really sucks badly. Will have to crack it. Never gonna pay 35 bucks for it.

Comment: I heard of reflector but i was quite unaware of its uses and i never used it myself so far. Thank you for the link, maybe i shall give the free version a spin some time.

Comment: @H.B.: Don't waste any time on Reflector; ILSpy is the future.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov *"Best .NET tool"* *"Will have to crack it. Never gonna pay 35 bucks for it."* ...Your concept of value is completely baffling to me.

Comment: Reflector 6.8.2.5 is the version I use. Free and without time limits.

Answer (score 8):

It does so by calling `InsertItem` which is overridden and can be seen upon decompilation

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
    this.CheckReentrancy();
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, too, Ani was faster though so i handed this one to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the key is not in overriding the base Collection methods, it's in the fact that you will be implementing the ICollection interface. And frankly, rather than inheriting from a Collection class, I would suggest instead creating an adapter class that takes a ICollection in the constructor and your methods will just delegate to the inner collection and raise the appropriate events.